# Fandom API Retrieve all pages in a category

Tags: api

I want to get all pages in a category using fandom api but I couldn't find a way to do it. There is allpages query property but it doesn't have any parameter related to category. Is there any other way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [Categorymembers API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers), you can get all the pages within a category. You'll need to use the API parameters

- **cmtitle**=(name of category),
- **cmlimit**=(maximum results returned, max 500 at a time)
- **list**=**categorymembers**

Note that if you want to paginate through more results than 500, you will need to also use the **cmcontinue** parameter returned in the first page of results in your next API query to get the second page of results.

[Here it is in action](https://simpsons.fandom.com/api.php?action=query&format=json&formatversion=2&list=categorymembers&cmlimit=500&cmtitle=Category%3ACharacters) on Fandom.